# Can I travel to Mexico to enter the USA as a British Citizen

Tags: usa, uk, covid-19, mexico

I am a British citizen who is trying to enter the USA to visit my girlfriend in Boston.

Would it be possible for me to fly from the UK to Mexico, reside there for two weeks (working remotely from an AirBnB), then fly from Mexico to the US?

If so, what travel documents would I need to prepare?

Also if there are other routes for a UK citizen to enter the US currently please let me know!

Comment: When are you hoping to travel? AFAIK there’s uncertainty whether yesterday’s lockdown announcement includes a ban on international travel from England, for example. Have you looked at https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/mexico/entry-requirements ? What would you do if the situation worsened while you were in Mexico?

Comment: That'd be a shame to be stuck in Cancun.

Comment: You’d also have to check if you are actually allowed to work while in Mexico on a a tourist visa or visa exemption. No idea what the rules are in Mexico.

Comment: And of course you’ll have the issue of getting back to the UK afterwards.

Comment: @Traveller with the current lockdown I guess I will be waiting before considering this. I have my fingers crossed for the London-New York corridor with testing, but I really appreciate the help exploring options.

Comment: @jcaron returning to the UK from the states wouldn't be as much of an issue, I'm lucky enough that WFH for two weeks upon arrival would be boring rather than a genuine problem. The wording for working on a tourist visa in Mexico isn't exactly clear, as it says I can't work while I'm there but the language makes it sound like I can't work for a Mexican business.

Comment: The UK travel lockdown begins on the 5th so in theory you could still get out if you fly today or tomorrow. Hope you make it.

Comment: @JordanMackie you can absolutely work remotely in Mexico on tourist permit, as long as you're not working for a Mexico company or getting paid to a Mexico bank (ie you're not taking a job from a Mexican).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be possible for me to fly from the UK to Mexico, reside there for two weeks (working remotely from an AirBnB), then fly from Mexico to the US?

Yes, assuming you can fly out of the UK (since you live there you're probably aware of the UK lockdown details). Unsure if Airbnb is currently operating in Mexico but hotels are. Also, in theory Mexico->US via land border is only open for essential business or US citizen/resident, so you might want to take the plane to be on the safe side.

Browse https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php to find other paths. E.g. Tanzania or Costa Rica works I believe, assuming you don't transit in a country banned by the US.